# How does third party tool get the code coverage lines

Tags: code-coverage, mavensmate

Does anyone share the same feeling with me that the code coverage tool from third party - like mavensmate - knows which lines are covered are quite awesome? It is not just in detecting the code coverage, it also helps debugging in a lot of cases. I am thinking of if this can be extended to wider usage - not just limited to test cases, would be quite awesome as well. Does anyone know the mechanism behind it so probably we can extend it to wider usage?

Comment: Everything that is used by tools such as MavensMate is expose through the Tooling API.

Comment: ... see e.g. [Tooling API PDF](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_toolingpre/api_tooling.pdf). You could also add your thoughts to [Feature: Test Runner highlight coverage in editor view](https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues/28).

Comment: Are you saying you would like to see which lines of code are run while a user is actually performing normal functions? Can you describe what you would use this for?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham My first thinking is about debugging. It directly tells me which lines are run and which are not and gives me a better view than debug log. Second is finding the dead code. Sometimes the dead code is not not easily discovered in a pre-existing org. By having that kind of tool we can examine the dead code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments ,the tooling API has the feature that tells you which lines are covered and which ones are not .

Taking some example from one of the blogs (http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2014/02/tooling-api-js-remoting-jsrender.html)

```
  @RemoteAction  
 public static String fetchCodeCoverage(){  
    return sendToolingQueryRequest('SELECT+NumLinesCovered,ApexClassOrTriggerId,ApexClassOrTrigger.Name ,NumLinesUncovered+FROM+ApexCodeCoverage');  
 }
```

Hence the tooling API returns the lines that are uncovered and also total no lines of class body and that should help us to highlight the lines thats covered and thats not covered .The blog link that i shared has the complete solution where author have built a VF code coverage tool.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems that the tooling API well returns the lines covered and uncovered for a test execution. But is it possible to get the covered and uncovered lines of code in a general use? I didn't see relevant fields.

Comment: Through tooling API rest query you will get that from Apex code coverage object and note this wont be available to you otherwise .only through tooling api REST or SOAP call it is available .